# RemoveDirectory contents from FTP server in C#

Tags: c#, ftp

How to delete the directory with sub directory and contents from FTP server in C#?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it with single command. You need to write a recursive method which first deletes subfolders and files.